# How to use async listener for SQS messages in springboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-jms

Can someone give me an example of how to listen to messages asynchronously via my springboot app? I currently am able to listen to messages synchronously like this.

```
@Autowired
protected JmsTemplate defaultJmsTemplate;


public void send(String message) {
    defaultJmsTemplate.convertAndSend("test-queue", MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build());

    logger.info("sent successfully");
}

@JmsListener(destination = "test-queue")
public void receive(String message)
{

    try {
        logger.info("message received: " + message);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.error(LoggingUtil.getStackTrace(e));;
    }

}
```

Also, can someone please tell how do i acknowledge individual messages here?

Comment: I don't understand the question; the `@JmsListener` __is__ asynchronous.

The container takes care of acknowledging the message when your method exits normally.

Comment: Two issues here: First, what happens if say my code inside try takes 10 seconds to execute per message and i get 10 messages in my queue?
second, i actually thought the same, but when i tried a simple exception like /0, message actually never came back to the queue, why is that?

Comment: The other messages will sit in the queue; you can increase the concurrency `spring.jms.listener.concurrency= # Minimum number of concurrent consumers.`. The session is transacted by default so, if you're using boot's default container factory, the message should be requeued - I just tested it with activemq and it works as expected.

Comment: I am using this for concurrency and acknowledge in the @config file
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(getSQSConnectionFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency("1-2");
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(SQSSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Should this be fine?